# How to select a string between two strings in a column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to get the string between two strings in a column of a table. How can I select the column? I have written the strings which are on either side. Can anyone help me how to include the column name with the string here?

```
DECLARE @Text NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(@Text, CHARINDEX('Manufacturer Name : ', @Text), 
                     CHARINDEX('Manufacturer Part',@text) - CHARINDEX('Manufacturer Name : ', @Text) + LEN('Manufacturer Part')) 
FROM 
    tbIMPACArchiveNew 
WHERE 
    (Description LIKE '%Manufacturer Name: %' 
     OR Description LIKE '%Manufacturer Name : %') 
    AND Description LIKE '%Manufacturer Part%'
```

Expected result:

```
Column A                                                       Expected result
Manufacturer Name : ABC Manufacturer Part Number : XVB-C2B4         ABC
Manufacturer Name : DEF Manufacturer Part Number : 3RH1924-1GP11    DEF
Manufacturer Name : ABJ Manufacturer Part Number : FLDP-IOM248-0001 ABJ
Manufacturer Name : HIJ Manufacturer Part Number : L12/5MLLD0035    HIJ
Manufacturer Name : abhkdk Manufacturer Part Number : PEH1083510    abhkdk
Manufacturer Name : 1245 PUMP Manufacturer Part Number : 02-1010-55 1245
```

Comment: `Manufacturer Name : ABC Manufacturer Part Number : XVB-C2B4` so this is all part of single column?

Comment: @AVK, Yes, all this is a part of a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to extract the text between two fixed strings.  Not exactly sure what you were doing with the @Text variable so I used it as an example below.

```
DECLARE @Text NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'blah blah Manufacturer Name : MY NAME Manufacturer Part blah blah'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Text, CHARINDEX('Manufacturer Name : ', @Text) + LEN('Manufacturer Name : ') + 1, CHARINDEX('Manufacturer Part',@Text) - (CHARINDEX('Manufacturer Name : ', @Text) + 2 + LEN('Manufacturer Name : ')) )

SELECT SUBSTRING(Description, CHARINDEX('Manufacturer Name : ', Description) + LEN('Manufacturer Name : ') + 1, CHARINDEX('Manufacturer Part',Description) - (CHARINDEX('Manufacturer Name : ', Description) + 2 + LEN('Manufacturer Name : ')) )
FROM tbIMPACArchiveNew 
WHERE Description LIKE '%Manufacturer Name : %Manufacturer Part'
```

Answer (score 3):

For a sample data of below

```
declare @table table (id int identity(1,1), data varchar(1000), descr varchar(1000))

insert into @table values ('Manufacturer Name : Manufacturer 1 Manufacturer Part : asjdfj','First Manufacturer')
insert into @table values ('Manufacturer Name : Manufacturer 2 Manufacturer Part : asjsadfasdfdfj','Second Manufacturer')
insert into @table values ('Manufacturer Name : Manufacturer 3 Manufacturer Part : er6ty','Third Manufacturer')
```

you can use

```
select substring(data, 
                 charindex('Manufacturer Name : ', data) + len('Manufacturer Name : '),
                 charindex('Manufacturer Part : ',data) - len('Manufacturer Part :') - 2) as Manufacturer_Name
       , descr
from @table
```

If you notice I am removing 2 characters at the end of substring to eliminate 'M' from `Manufacturer Part` and the Space before the actual text. You can use `RTRIM` but i chose this way.

Comment: I think you could repalce `charindex('Manufacturer Name : ', data) + len('Manufacturer Name : ')` with `20` , good answer

Comment: @ali The reason why i did not do that is because what if data data not start with `Manufacturer Name`? If the data is always consistent then your suggestion is good.

Comment: But when I modify the code and execute, I'm getting below error.
Msg 537, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: @Madhukar this is a working example. What did you modify? can you show your modified code? update the question?

Comment: Modified code:
select substring(Description, 
                 charindex('Manufacturer Name : ', Description) + len('Manufacturer Name : '),
                 charindex('Manufacturer Part : ',Description) - len('Manufacturer Part :') - 2) as Manufacturer_Name
       , Description
from tbIMPACArchieveNew where Description like '%Manufacturer name%'

Answer (score 0):

I think this what you want

```
SELECT SUBSTRING ( Description , 20 , CHARINDEX("Manufacturer Part") - 20)
FROM  tbIMPACArchiveNew;
```

where `20` is the length of *"Manufacturer Name : "*

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index of 4th space and remove the first 20.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING ( Description , 20 , instr(Description,' ',1,4 ) - 20)
FROM  tbIMPACArchiveNew;
```